# Docker read value form bashrc

Tags: java, bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a java jar in docker file and trying to read the jvm arg set in bashrc . This value is set using a shell script .But when i check the java process running inside the container , i dont see the jvm arg in the process output . Value is present in bashrc.
Also echo $JVM_ARGS shows proper value inside the container.
Dockerfile

```
FROM quay.io/nord-store-eng/base-java8:1.1.1
RUN mkdir -p /opt/test
COPY ./docker.jar /opt/test/docker.jar
COPY ./setenv.sh /opt/test/setenv.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/test/setenv.sh
RUN /opt/test/setenv.sh
CMD ["sh","-c","java $JVM_ARGS -jar /opt/test/docker.jar"]
```

Process output 
[image: ps command output]

Comment: Which .bashrc?.

Comment: In setenv.sh, i am adding the entry to user bashrc .
echo export JVM_ARGS="\"-Xmx512m\"" >> ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you are using sh, which isn't reading from your bashrc.

> --norc Do not read and execute the system wide initialization file
>   /etc/bash.bashrc and the personal initialization file ~/.bashrc if the
>   shell is interactive. This option is on by default if the shell is
>   invoked as sh.
>   - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94494/54089

Can you try specifying 'bash' rather than 'sh'?

```
CMD ["bash","-c","java $JVM_ARGS -jar /opt/test/docker.jar"]
```

Or keeping sh (e.g. alpine doesn't have bash):

```
CMD ["sh","-c","source ~/.bashrc; java $JVM_ARGS -jar /opt/test/docker.jar"]
```

Or keeping sh, absolute path to bashrc:

```
CMD ["sh","-c","source /root/.bashrc; java $JVM_ARGS -jar /opt/test/docker.jar"]
```